# Instances MAC Address

Tags: python, gcloud

Is there a way to get MAC address of a VM Instance using `gcloud` or python's `googleapiclient` package?
I'm not talking about `gcloud compute ssh ...` .

Comment: In Google Cloud MAC addresses are generated based on IP addresses. So if you use the same IP later for a different resource (like VM) the IP will be associated with the same MAC address.

In on-premises environments MAC addresses are frequently associated with network interfaces/cards. This is not the case in Google Cloud. 

Going back to your original question, I do not know a method to obtain the MAC address.

Comment: No, Google does not provide an API to fetch the MAC address of a VM instance. Note: the MAC address is calculated (hash) based on the internal IP of an instance. Edit your question to show a problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

No, Google does not provide an API to fetch the MAC address of a VM instance. Note: the MAC address is calculated (hash) based on the internal IP of an instance.

So, if you use the same IP later for a different resource (like VM) the IP will be associated with the same MAC address. In on-premises environments, MAC addresses are frequently associated to network interfaces/cards. This is not the case in Google Cloud.

There is already a related future request that you can follow [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/124605415).

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Cruising the web I see that the hashing algorithm is not a public knowledge. Is it still the case?

Comment: Yes, it is due to privacy reasons. You can follow the related discussion in [this group](https://groups.google.com/g/gce-discussion/c/Xw5eUd8sCXA).